# Exposing port in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, curl, hashicorp-vault

So I added:

```
# expose port 8200
EXPOSE 8200

# run a script
ENTRYPOINT ["helloworld/run.sh"]
```

to my `Dockerfile` that should have been exposed port `8200`. And then I build & run it:

```
docker build --tag my-service .
docker run my-service --network="host"
```

and then here's a part of my `run.sh`:

```
cd helloworld/
export VAULT_TOKEN='token123'
export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'
export TF_VAR_issuer_url='http://localhost:8200'
# Start Vault as a server in "dev" mode in a background and ignore its output
vault server -dev -dev-root-token-id=${VAULT_TOKEN} # &>/dev/null &
curl http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/health # https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/health
```

the problem is, `curl` command prints out:

```
+ curl http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/health
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8200: Connection refused
```

even though locally when I run a dev server it prints out:

```
➜  $ curl http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/health
{"initialized":true,"sealed":false,"standby":false,"performance_standby":false,"replication_performance_mode":"disabled","replication_dr_mode":"disabled","server_time_utc":1608149576,"version":"1.5.4","cluster_name":"vault-cluster-1497c401","cluster_id":"98c78719-d8fc-2423-66bd-7e036654ba16"}
```

so it's probably something wrong with the way I expose the port `8200` or something.

Update: as a temporary fix, I made `export LOCALHOST='host.docker.internal'` and it works now but I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: You need to use -p parameter in docker run command. expose in Dockerfile only exposes port to docker container but u are using host port.. for that u need to expose port using -p paramter . try docker run my-service -p 8200:8200 --network="host"

Comment: Hmm, let me try that. Just to make sure, I do want to run that `curl` from the container itself.

Comment: You probably don't want host networking.  Among other things, the `-p` option @Rezwan suggests is completely ignored with it.  Conversely, "expose" as a verb is also almost meaningless in modern Docker, so don't fixate on that either.  You might try launching the Vault server as a foreground process, and as the only process in its container, and running the client from somewhere else.

Comment: I wonder if the Vault server is just not up yet - have you tried adding a wait of a few seconds into your script between starting the server and the `curl` command?